# Using object methods to do a php callback

Tags: php, function, syntax, delegates, semantics

Is this possible?

for example, if I have the following function which uses an object...

```
private function getValues($id, $table, $columns = '*',  $idKey = 'id', $ret) {

        $db = JFactory::getDBO();

        $query = 
        "SELECT `{$amount}` FROM `{$table}` 
        WHERE `{$idKey}` = " . $db->getEscaped($id);

        return $db->$ret();
    }
```

...and uses the following call...

```
$ret = 'loadAssoc';

$values = getValues('0', 'sometable', '*', 'id', $ret);
```

...providing the `$ret` variable represents an actual method which exists in the class definition of the object, will this work? I'd like to know if not, why not[?] as well.

Comment: What is your results? When you tried, Was it worked?

Comment: When I tried it my html/css didn't load. :/. I'll post a var_dump here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can provide is that I'm currently not even able to var_dump() a query such as this. Furthermore, the Html and Css which were supposed to load along with the form I was testing this on simply wouldn't load, and the query would produce an automatic die, without error. I'm guessing in this current installation of PHP, while not being a syntax error (technically, as no error is thrown), this simply throws the parser out of whack and forces its tail between its lags, in addition to a non-computational piece of data being thrown down its throat.